# deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations) - issue with service method invoking

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-scheduled

I have faced with strange problem regarding deleting child object from association.

Here is my first object **Order**:

```
 @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", orphanRemoval=true)
 @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
 private List<ExchangeTransaction> exchangeTransactions = new ArrayList<ExchangeTransaction>();
```

Here is my second object **ExchangeTransaction**:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "orderId", insertable = true, updatable = false)
private Order order;
```

I want to delete Order with all related ExchangeTransactions.

If I perform delete operation through controller, everything works fine. Here is code inside controller:

```
 Order order = orderService.getOrder(orderId);
 User user = order.getUser();
 user.removeOrder(order);
 orderService.removeOrder(order);
```

If delete operation is performed by @Scheduled service, I've got error message:

> ERROR
>   [org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler]
>   [] pool-3-thread-1 Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: deleted
>   object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from
>   associations): [currencyexchange.model.ExchangeTransaction#2];

Code inside service object:

```
@Override
@Transactional
@Scheduled(cron = "*/30 * * * * *")
    public void deleteInactiveOrders() {
        orderDAO.deleteInactiveOrders();
    }
```

Code inside DAO:

```
@Override
public void deleteInactiveOrders() {
List<Order> allInactiveOrdersList = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Order where orderDate <= sysdate-1").list();
    if (allInactiveOrdersList.size() >=1 ){
        for (Order order: allInactiveOrdersList){
            User user = order.getUser();
            user.removeOrder(order);
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(order);
        }
      }
    }
```

UPDATE: this is not @Scheduled issue. When I invoke deleteInactiveOrders() from the controller I've got the same error.

Comment: Does the order that is deleted in the controller contain any `ExchangeTransaction`s? If not, could you try to delete one which does? Also, I assume that you set the `Order`'s `user` field to null in `user.removeOrder(order)`?

Comment: Yes, the order which deleted through controller contains ExchangeTransaction and delete operation is processed successfully. But when the same operation is performed by @Scheduled service I've got an error. Yes, inside removeOrder method I have such line order.setUser(null);

Comment: And, when you invoke `deleteInactiveOrders` from the controller, what happens? Does it fail there as well?

Comment: I forgot to check this case, yes when i invoke deleteInactiveOrders from the controller, it fails with the same error. But when I place almost the same code into controller - it works well.

Comment: Ok, then we know that the context in which it is executed is not the cause of the issue. Could you turn `exchangeTransactions` to a lazy collection (`LazyCollectionOption.TRUE`) and then retry `deleteInactiveOrders`?

Comment: Done. But error has remained.

Comment: Ok, and when you invoke `order.getExchangeTransactions().clear()` before you delete the order?

Comment: I don't use clear(). But when I place order.getExchangeTransactions().clear() before user.removeOrder(order); nothing has changed, error has remained.

Comment: Hm, then I think you'll have to provide us with full entity mappings for User, Order and ExchangeTransaction entities.

Comment: I've fixed this issue. It was required to set FetchType.LAZY to exchangeTransactions in User object. But in Order object LazyCollectionOption must be FALSE.

Comment: That's why I asked for all the mappings. :) I assumed that user also referenced `ExchangeTransaction`s. And in general, you did not fix the issue. It will come back as soon as you attempt this in a context where user's exchangeTransactions collection is initialized.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail your last comment and what is the better way to fix this problem?

Comment: Sure, just to verify my suspicion, could you just add `user.getExchangeTransactions().size()` as the first statement in the loop? If you get the same error back again, then my assumption is correct.

Comment: Did you mean something like this:
`for (Order order: allInactiveOrdersList){
       User user = order.getUser();
       user.getTransactions().size();
       user.removeOrder(order);
       sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(order);`

With code above I didn't get error: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade.

Comment: Well, more like `for (Order order: allInactiveOrdersList){
    order.getUser().getTransactions().size();
}` You could add it before the existing loop. I assume that `getTransactions()` returns the collection that you changed to be lazy.

Comment: No, I didn't manage to get error with the following code: `for (Order order: allInactiveOrdersList){ order.getUser().getTransactions().size(); }`

Comment: Ok, still I'm afraid that something is wrong. If the correctness of the program logic depends on whether a collection is lazy or not, then something is not right and you have a hidden issue that may appear in the future when you change the code.